# Alter Object type body [PL/SQL]

Tags: plsql

i´m triying to alter a body type of an object. Here is my code:

```
ALTER TYPE Profesor ADD CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Profesor(codigo INTEGER, nombre 
VARCHAR2, 
primerApellido VARCHAR2, segundoApellido VARCHAR2, especialidad VARCHAR2)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT CASCADE;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Profesor AS CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Profesor(codigo 
INTEGER, nombre VARCHAR2, 
primerApellido VARCHAR2, segundoApellido VARCHAR2, especialidad VARCHAR2)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
BEGIN 
  SELF.codigo := codigo;
  SELF.nombre := nombre;
  SELF.apellidos := primerApellido||' '||segundoApellido;
  SELF.especialidad := especialidad;
  RETURN;
END;
END;
/
```

I´ve created the Object and then i altered it adding a constructor and creating a type body.
The code doesn´t show errors but if i try to add a new method it lets me add the method but not de code:

```
ALTER TYPE Profesor ADD MEMBER FUNCTION getNombreCompleto RETURN VARCHAR2 
 CASCADE;
 /
 ALTER TYPE BODY Profesor ADD MEMBER FUNCTION getNombreCompleto RETURN 
 VARCHAR2 
 CASCADE 
 IS
 BEGIN
 RETURN SELF.nombre;
 END getNombreCompleto;
 END;
```

And that´s the question, how can i  alter the body type of an object?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to alter type instead of  using "create or replace"  for whole type.?

Comment: Because if i create or replace the whole type body it replaces all the type body, droping the code of constructor.

Comment: It's not exactly dropping anything. You edit your source code and run it to compile it, the same as any other language such as Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution should work. `Alter type member function\ constructor` works only for type specification. For body you have to recreate body.

```
ALTER TYPE Profesor ADD CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Profesor(codigo INTEGER, nombre 
VARCHAR2, 
primerApellido VARCHAR2, segundoApellido VARCHAR2, especialidad VARCHAR2)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT CASCADE;
/

ALTER TYPE Profesor ADD MEMBER FUNCTION getNombreCompleto RETURN VARCHAR2 
 CASCADE;
 /
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Profesor AS 
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Profesor(codigo 
INTEGER, nombre VARCHAR2, 
primerApellido VARCHAR2, segundoApellido VARCHAR2, especialidad VARCHAR2)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
BEGIN 
  SELF.codigo := codigo;
  SELF.nombre := nombre;
  SELF.apellidos := primerApellido||' '||segundoApellido;
  SELF.especialidad := especialidad;
  RETURN;
END;

 MEMBER FUNCTION getNombreCompleto RETURN 
 VARCHAR2 
 CASCADE 
 IS
 BEGIN
 RETURN SELF.nombre;
 END getNombreCompleto;
 END;
END;
/
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I thought there would be a way to not rewrite all the written code and add new methods without rewrite all the body type. Thank you!